# How to add date and HHMM time together into month/date/year hh:mm format and index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I'm working with a CSV file with flight records. My overall goal is to make plots of flight delays over a few selected days. I am trying to index these flights by the day and the scheduled departure times. So, I have a flight date in a month/day/year format and a departure time formated in hhmm, is there a way to reformat that departure time column to a hh:mm format in 24:00 time? Then would I simply add the columns together and index by them?

I've tried adding the columns together without reformatting the time and I'm not sure matplotlib recognizes this time format for my plots.

```
data = pd.read_csv("groundhog_query.csv",parse_dates=[['Flight_Date', 'Scheduled_Dep_Time']]) 
data.index = data['Flight_Date_Scheduled_Dep_Time']
data
```

## the CSV files looks like this

'''
Year,Flight_Date,Day_Of_Year,Unique_Carrier_ID,Airline_ID,Tail_Number,Flight_Number,Origin_Airport_ID,Origin_Market_ID,Origin_Airport_Code,Origin_State,Destination_Airport_ID,Destination_Market_ID,Destination_Airport_Code,Dest_State,Scheduled_Dep_Time,Actual_Dep_Time,Dep_Delay,Pos_Dep_Delay,Scheduled_Arr_Time,Actual_Arr_Time,Arr_Delay,Pos_Arr_Delay,Combined_Arr_Delay,Can_Status,Can_Reason,Div_Status,Scheduled_Elapsed_Time,Actual_Elapsed_Time,Carrier_Delay,Weather_Delay,Natl_Airspace_System_Delay,Security_Delay,Late_Aircraft_Delay,Div_Airport_Landings,Div_Landing_Status,Div_Elapsed_Time,Div_Arrival_Delay,Div_Airport_1_ID,Div_1_Tail_Num,Div_Airport_2_ID,Div_2_Tail_Num,Div_Airport_3_ID,Div_3_Tail_Num,Div_Airport_4_ID,Div_4_Tail_Num,Div_Airport_5_ID,Div_5_Tail_Num
2011,2011-01-24,24,MQ,20398,N717MQ,4527,11278,30852,DCA,VA,14492,34492,RDU,NC,1630,1622.0,-8.0,0.0,1735,1722.0,-13.0,0.0,-13.0,0,,0,65,60.0,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2011,2011-01-25,25,MQ,20398,N736MQ,4527,11278,30852,DCA,VA,14492,34492,RDU,NC,1630,1624.0,-6.0,0.0,1735,1724.0,-11.0,0.0,-11.0,0,,0,65,60.0,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2011,2011-01-26,26,MQ,20398,N737MQ,4527,11278,30852,DCA,VA,14492,34492,RDU,NC,1630,,,,1735,,,,,1,B,0,65,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2011,2011-01-27,27,MQ,20398,N721MQ,4527,11278,30852,DCA,VA,14492,34492,RDU,NC,1630,1832.0,122.0,122.0,1735,1936.0,121.0,121.0,121.0,0,,0,65,64.0,121.0,0.0,0.0,0.
'''

my current results are in a month/day/year hhmm format

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps:
1. Read CSV without parsing dates.
2. Merge 'Flight_Date' and 'Scheduled_Dep_Time' columns. Make sure that 'Scheduled_Dep_Time' is converted to string fist (hence .map(str)) since it is by default parsed as int.
3. Convert string to datetime by using correct format ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
4. Set this newly produced column as index

```py
d = pd.read_csv("groundhog_query.csv")
d['Flight_Date_Scheduled_Dep_Time_string'] = d.Flight_Date.str.cat(' ' + d.Scheduled_Dep_Time.map(str))
d['Flight_Date_Scheduled_Dep_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(d.Flight_Date_Scheduled_Dep_Time_string, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
d = d.set_index('Flight_Date_Scheduled_Dep_Time')
```

The reference for % directives is here:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pandas, would this be making a date and time string from scratch and then joining it to my existing data frame? If so I'm looking to take a pre-existing time column and date column and reformate them into DateTime. Thanks for the help

Comment: It is a bit difficult to write exact code since there is no example data which is why I created it from scratch. But you can use the last 2 lines with your data. Could you post an example of date and time directly from CSV?

Comment: I've added a sample of the csv above now

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')